# Is it appropriate to use VO + A command to read page including non-text (e.g. radio button, etc)

Tags: accessibility, voiceover

I feel much confused about whether it is appropriate or not to use VO + A command to read page including none-text. I have a problem that VoiceOver would read the name twice in Safari while using this command to read document including radio button. Or it is a bug?

Comment: Is this only for mac?

Comment: @E.Coms Yes, in Safari.

Comment: demo: https://jsbin.com/velerus/edit?html,output